# In how many ways can I put the numbers in the table?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Let's  a table $10×10$. I put the numbers 0, 1, 2,..., 8, 9 s.t. on any line or columns there are not  2 numbers s.t. their sum is 10.

In how many ways can I put the numbers in the table?

I have no idea how to start.

Comment: @Pspl 1 and 9 are not on the same line or column. 2 and 8 are not in the same line or column. And so on.

Comment: @Arthur, thanks!

Comment: Are you putting 100 numbers into a 10 x 10 array? Or just one copy of each of 0,1,...,9?

Comment: A quick remark is that you have some sort of boundary at $5$. You can put all numbers you want if all of them are in $\{0, \dots, 4\}$, or if all of them are in $\{6,\dots,9\}$. You can even add 10 fives on the diagonal, or less than 10 five that do not meet each other to any of the previous case.

Comment: I suppose that a good starting point would be a table with only $\{0,\dots,4\}$ where you try to add step by step higher numbers.

Comment: @almagest One copy of each of them